# SoapUI Load Plugins throws Security Exception - has unsigned class files

Tags: java, plugins, soapui

I am trying to create a new Plugin for SoapUI(Open Source).I have followed the [steps mentioned here](http://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/developing-plugins/plugin-development.html) to create a plugin.

After building the project I [placed the jar file in plugins folder](http://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/install.html) in `user\.soapuios\plugins`.[As plugin manager wont be available for free version]

When SoapUI is launched the plugin is not getting loaded.Its throwing the below error that `plugin has unsigned class`.

> SoapUI 5.2.1 OpenSource
>   Windows 7

```
2016-01-11 17:02:58,736 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [The plugin 'C:\Users\xxxx\.soapuios\plugins\testplugin-1.0.0.jar' has unsigned class files.], see error log for details
2016-01-11 17:02:58,752 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.SecurityException: The plugin 'C:\Users\525372\.soapuios\plugins\testplugin-1.0.0.jar' has unsigned class files.
java.lang.SecurityException: The plugin 'C:\Users\525372\.soapuios\plugins\testplugin-1.0.0.jar' has unsigned class files.
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.ProductBodyguard$JarVerifier.verify(ProductBodyguard.java:107)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.ProductBodyguard.isKnown(ProductBodyguard.java:39)
    at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:93)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.loadPlugins(DefaultSoapUICore.java:155)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.init(DefaultSoapUICore.java:133)
    at com.eviware.soapui.StandaloneSoapUICore.<init>(StandaloneSoapUICore.java:38)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI$SoapUIRunner.run(SoapUI.java:721)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-01-11 17:02:58,783 WARN  [SoapUI] Plugin 'testplugin-1.0.0.jar' is not loaded because it hasn't been signed by SmartBear Software.
```

Comment: You may give a try on SoapUI OS 5.2.0 till you get your plugin signed by _Smartbear_ in order to use in 5.2.1. Just curious, what does your plugin do?

Comment: @Rao Isn't it obvious.Whatever that's not in soap ui free.To be precise the testdata part..

Comment: Of course, Madhan. Otherwise, need does not arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Do-i-have-to-sign-my-plugin-from-SoapUI-5-2-1-on/td-p/108694) it looks like that **from 5.2.1 onwards** the standard **SoapUI will not accept plugins from unkown sources.** The Community Manager (SmartBear employee) wrote:

> As far as I know some changes with the plugin manager were implemented
>   in SoapUI 5.2.1.  Since that, only SmartBear-made plugins can work
>   with the new manager.
>
> I can suggest the following options for you:
>
> - You can send your plugin at soapuiplugins@smartbear.com. Our team will review it and add to the product.
> - You can consider moving to SoapUI NG - user-made plugins are allowed here. SoapUI NG is the newest SoapUI version and it is
>     included into Ready! API.

*If you check the thread, you might also find some other suggestion that could be helpful in your case. (there is a hack to bypass this protection for testing purposes)*